# WPF Ribbon - sample/open source application

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Is there any good open source WPF application that's using Ribbon?
I would like to see how Ribbon is used in pratical applications (outside of Office apps)...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple [WPF demo](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/hands-on-labs/entry76491.aspx) using a ribbon UI at WindowsClient.Net labs.

Comment: I saw this demo... do you know of any more advanced demo/application? Even if it's not open source...

Comment: "more advanced" in what way? A ribbon is just a container; is a list with more items "more advanced"? If so, then add more controls to your ribbon. If you want a complete application that happens to use a ribbon, look in http://www.codeplex.com/. Note that the ribbon control in a huge application is no different from the ribbon in the demo. If you're asking for examples of ribbon appearance or behavior, then Office is your best example.

Comment: I'm looki for real app use, not just a simple demo. I would like to see applications using Ribbon, how they used ribbon.